# Centripetal force and constant speed

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

This may seem like a trivial question, and I'm having a little trouble fleshing out my issues with the answers Ive seen so be prepared for some discussion on your answer. But why does centripetal force not change the speed?

I keep coming to this crux. If you have an initial velocity $v$ and then have a force $f$ at right angles to it. Would the new velocity not be greater than $v$ by pythagoras? How can it remain constant?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113102).

Comment: Check the answers here for more intuition: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312492/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a perpendicular force not change speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113102/)

Comment: Although I believe that his question was better formatted I do not believe theain answer actually answers the question sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If the force had a component in the direction of the velocity it would increase the speed.  If it had a component in a direction opposite to the velocity it would decrease the speed.  Because the centripetal force is perpendicular to the velocity it does neither.